# Data passing in async.waterfall model is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger-node-express

I want to pass the data 1 and data 2 to the last function directly.
It is working when I pass data 1 to second function and from there data 1 + data 2 to the last function. But the problem is that I don't want to pass data 1 to the second function. Can we do it with `'asyc.series'` and `'async.parallel'`?.

```
 var fs = require("fs");
    var async = require('async');
    async.waterfall([
        myFirstFunction,
        mySecondFunction,            

    ], function (err,data1,data2) {
        var values={'data1':data1,'data2':data2,'msg':"hai"}
       console.log("values: %j", values);
    });
    function myFirstFunction(callback) {
          fs.readFile('file1.js','utf8',function(err,data1){
          callback(null,data1);
           });
    }
    function mySecondFunction(callback) {
         fs.readFile('file2.js','utf8',function(err,data2){
          callback(null,data2);
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it with [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback)

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require('async');
async.parallel([
    myFirstFunction,
    mySecondFunction,            

], function (err, results) {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    var data1 = results[0];
    var data1 = results[1];
});

function myFirstFunction(callback) {
    fs.readFile('file1.js','utf8',function(err,data1){
        callback(null,data1);
    });
}

function mySecondFunction(callback) {
    fs.readFile('file2.js','utf8',function(err,data2){
        callback(null,data2);
    });
}
```